# How to operator join two matrix in raku-lang？

Tags: r, raku

Is there have something like R-lang columnbind or rowbind in raku.
[R-lang cbind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58hbl.jpg)

e.g.

```
my @matrix = ^100 .rotor(10);
my @cbind = cbind( @matrix [*;1..2].rotor(2) , @matrix [*;3..4].rotor(2) )
my @rbind = rbind ( @matrix [1..2;*].rotor(10) , @matrix [3..4;*].rotor(10) ）
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rbind` is straightforward:

```
my @one = <a b c d>.rotor(2);
my @two = <e f g h>.rotor(2);
say @one.append: @two;
```

*Update*: edited thanks to comment.

> If order does not matter so much, you can just use ∪ and it will turn into a set.

`cbind` is a bit trickier, but doable:

```
say (@one Z @two).map( { @_.map: |* } )
```

[`Z`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/Z) is the *zip* operator, which will interleave the elements of the first and the second list. But then well have too many nested lists, so we need to flatten the inner list here: `{ @_.map: |* }`. That will output

```
((a b e f) (c d g h))
```

Comment: Instead of `push` you can use `append` to avoid using the slip